# Merge 2 files with awk while filling in missing values with 'NA'

Tags: arrays, sorting, awk, merge

File 1:

```
chr1:763668:T:C, C, T, 0.002, 0.001, 0, 0.001, 0.002, 0.002, 0.003, 0, 0.002, 0.690
chr1:775340:A:G, G, A, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.001, 0
chr1:781598:C:T, T, C, 0, 0, 0, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0, 0, 0.688
chr1:781706:A:C, C, A, 0, 0, 0.687, 0, 0, 0.003, 0, 0, 0.002, 0
chr1:782519:A:G, G, A, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.001
```

File 2:

```
chr1:763668:T:C, C, T, 0.004, 0.001, 0, 0.002, 0, 0.001, 0.003, 0, 0.001, 0
chr1:775340:A:G, G, A, 0, 0, 0.687, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
chr1:781706:A:C, C, A, 0.771, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.003, 0.001
chr1:782519:A:G, G, A, 0, 0, 0, 0.802, 0, 0, 0, 0.002, 0, 0.002
chr1:787139:A:G, G, A, 0.001, 0.001, 0, 0.001, 0.003, 0.006, 0.002, 0, 0.003, 0.011
```

In merged file, for each column 1 identifier (in file 1 and/or file 2), data present in one file but not the other needs to be represented with NA's. The file needs to be sorted on the numerical value in column 1 (eg chr1:**763668**:T:C)

Desired output file:

```
chr1:763668:T:C, C, T, 0.002, 0.001, 0, 0.001, 0.002, 0.002, 0.003, 0, 0.002, 0.690, 0.004, 0.001, 0, 0.002, 0, 0.001, 0.003, 0, 0.001, 0
chr1:775340:A:G, G, A, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0.687, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
chr1:781598:C:T, T, C, 0, 0, 0, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0, 0, 0.688, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
chr1:781706:A:C, C, A, 0, 0, 0.687, 0, 0, 0.003, 0, 0, 0.002, 0, 0, 0, 0.687, 0, 0, 0.003, 0, 0, 0.002, 0
chr1:782519:A:G, G, A, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0.802, 0, 0, 0, 0.002, 0, 0.002
chr1:787139:A:G, G, A, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.001, 0.001, 0, 0.001, 0.003, 0.006, 0.002, 0, 0.003, 0.011
```

Code based on previous assistance with a similar request:

```
awk 'BEGIN{filler="NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA"}
 {
                c1[$1]=$1
                c2[$1]=$2
                rest=substr($0, index($0, $3))

                if(NR==FNR){
                crest[$2]=rest
        }
        else{
                if(crest[$2]==""){
                        crest[$2]=filler OFS rest}
                else{
                        crest[$2]=crest[$2] OFS rest
                }
        }
        }
        END{
                for(i in c2){
                        print c1[i],c2[i],crest[i],filler
        }
}' file1 file2 | awk 'NF=26' | sort -k 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
cat merge.awk

BEGIN {
   filler = "NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA"
   FS = OFS = ", "
}
{
   k = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3
}
FNR == NR {
   sub(/^([^,]+, ){3}/, "")
   map[k] = $0
   next
}
{
   print $0, (k in map ? map[k] : filler)
   delete map[k]
}
END {
   for (i in map)
      print i, filler, map[i]
}
```

Then use it as:

```sh
awk -f merge.awk file2 file1
```

```
chr1:763668:T:C, C, T, 0.002, 0.001, 0, 0.001, 0.002, 0.002, 0.003, 0, 0.002, 0.690, 0.004, 0.001, 0, 0.002, 0, 0.001, 0.003, 0, 0.001, 0
chr1:775340:A:G, G, A, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0.687, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
chr1:781598:C:T, T, C, 0, 0, 0, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0, 0, 0.688, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
chr1:781706:A:C, C, A, 0, 0, 0.687, 0, 0, 0.003, 0, 0, 0.002, 0, 0.771, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.003, 0.001
chr1:782519:A:G, G, A, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0.802, 0, 0, 0, 0.002, 0, 0.002
chr1:787139:A:G, G, A, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.001, 0.001, 0, 0.001, 0.003, 0.006, 0.002, 0, 0.003, 0.011
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava, I made a few adjustments and was able to get the code to run with desired output. Would it be possible to change this code to adjust for a variable number of columns in either input file (ie file 1 and file 2 to be merged)? For example, can we "count" the number of data columns in file 1 or file 2 and fill them in with as many NAs when there's a missing field (ie no "fixed" filler)?

Comment: Answer is based on the question asked and sample data you provided. If your actual data is different from what is posted here then update your question and provide expected output